# How do you count how many times a nested for loop iterates?

Tags: java

In the code below, I can trace how many times each of the for loops iterate if I look at them separately. For example, both the for loops iterate 10 times however, when you put them together, the String "hi" prints out more than 20 times.

How many times does the inner loop iterate?

```
for(int j=0; j<10; j++) 
    for(int k=10; k>0; k--)
        System.out.println("hi");
```

Comment: If you do ten things ten times, then you have done 100 things.

Comment: as @ElliottFrisch said, `hi` will be printed 100 times

Comment: Oh I see. So was I correct when I said that the inner loop iterates 10 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as multiplying how many each iterate together (in this case 10*10). If you are finding it isn't as simple as this, you can perform the following test:

```
int count = 0;
for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
    for(int k=10; k>0; k--){
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println("The nested loop iterated " + String.valueOf(count) + " times!");
```

Edit: Perhaps an easier way to understand what is going on:

```
int total_count = 0;
for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
    System.out.println("The outer loop has iterated " + String.valueOf(j+1) + " times!"); 
    System.out.println("Executing the inner loop");   
    int local_count = 0;
    for(int k=10; k>0; k--){
        local_count ++;
        total_count ++;
        System.out.println("Inner loop #" + String.valueOf(j+1) + " has iterated " + String.valueOf(local_count) + " times!");
        System.out.println("The inner loop's total iterations are " + String.valueOf(total_count) + " times!");
    }
}
System.out.println("The nested loop iterated " + String.valueOf(total_count) + " times!");
```

Comment: This test print out that the nested loop iterates 100 times. Does that mean that it is not viewed separate from the other loop?

Comment: It is separate in the sense that each time the outer loop iterates the value of k is reset to 10, so the inner loop restarts. 

But because the outer loop iterates 10 times and the inner loop is INSIDE the outer loop, the inner loop is executed 10 times and iterates 10 times (10 x 10). So code within the inner loop will execute 100 times.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand. However, is asking "How many times does the **inner** loop iterate?" and "How many times does the **nested** loop iterate?" different? If they are different my understanding is that the inner loop iterates 10 times and the nested loop iterates 100 times. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You are right but it is important to know the nested loop is iterating 10 x 10 times. It is different from 100 times, as the value of k is reset to 10 each time.

Very different from something like `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){ // inside loop }`

Comment: Sorry for so many edits, the second example should work now :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with nested loops always try to visualize the first loop `j` as the row and the second loop `k` as the column.

[image]

The rows go `left-to-right` and the columns go `top-to-bottom`. If you multiply the `row x column` size then that is usually how many iterations you will encounter.

Comment: From this, my understanding is that the nested loop iterates 10 times but, the whole program iterates 100 times?

Comment: @ally The row (j in your case) iterates 10 times. Column (k in your case) iterates 10 times. Since you have nested the loops you are multiplying `j x k`, thus the nested loop iterates 100 times.

Comment: Did you really just bust out a multiplication table to answer a question? -_-

Comment: I think the multiplication table is fine, it gives ally a visual explanation of @coletrain answer.